# JQuery without a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a cycling image slider and have a question about a document I'm referencing for development.

The JQuery function doesn't actually call a selector and I'm not exactly sure how to read it.

```
$.fn.cycle = function(options, arg2) {
var o = { s: this.selector, c: this.context };
```

The script above is in my javascript document and the method below is in my HTML doc calling to the script above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.headline').cycle({
    fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, 
    cleartypeNoBg:true
});
```

.headline is a class that is defined in the HTML document. I'm confused because this has a selector and $.fn.cycle does not.

Is .headline passing in the value to .fn? If so, how is it passing in only to that section of the variable?

If you wish to see the full JQuery function it is here:

```
$.fn.cycle = function(options, arg2) {
var o = { s: this.selector, c: this.context };

// in 1.3+ we can fix mistakes with the ready state
if (this.length === 0 && options != 'stop') {
    if (!$.isReady && o.s) {
        log('DOM not ready, queuing slideshow');
        $(function() {
            $(o.s,o.c).cycle(options,arg2);
        });
        return this;
    }
    // is your DOM ready?  http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()
    log('terminating; zero elements found by selector' + ($.isReady ? '' : ' (DOM not ready)'));
    return this;
}

// iterate the matched nodeset
return this.each(function() {
    var opts = handleArguments(this, options, arg2);
    if (opts === false)
        return;

    opts.updateActivePagerLink = opts.updateActivePagerLink || $.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink;

    // stop existing slideshow for this container (if there is one)
    if (this.cycleTimeout)
        clearTimeout(this.cycleTimeout);
    this.cycleTimeout = this.cyclePause = 0;

    var $cont = $(this);
    var $slides = opts.slideExpr ? $(opts.slideExpr, this) : $cont.children();
    var els = $slides.get();
    if (els.length < 2) {
        log('terminating; too few slides: ' + els.length);
        return;
    }

    var opts2 = buildOptions($cont, $slides, els, opts, o);
    if (opts2 === false)
        return;

    var startTime = opts2.continuous ? 10 : getTimeout(els[opts2.currSlide], els[opts2.nextSlide], opts2, !opts2.rev);

    // if it's an auto slideshow, kick it off
    if (startTime) {
        startTime += (opts2.delay || 0);
        if (startTime < 10)
            startTime = 10;
        debug('first timeout: ' + startTime);
        this.cycleTimeout = setTimeout(function(){go(els,opts2,0,(!opts2.rev && !opts.backwards))}, startTime);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.fn.cycle` it's a jquery plugin not a function

Comment: This is a great place to start - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: @mgraph: `typeof $.fn.cycle` would disagree. Of course it's a function, but it is used to extend jQuery, which makes it a plugin.

Comment: `$.fn.cycle = function()` extends jQuery with a plugin that can be used on jQuery objects like; `$('.headline').cycle(...);`

Comment: `$.fn.cycle` means that `cycle` becomes a jQuery method, which means that it can be invoked on jQuery instances. A selector is used to select various elements when creating a new jQuery instance. Once you create a new jQuery instance, you can invoke `cycle` on it.

Comment: `$.fn.cycle` is a function that defines a plugin.

Comment: Plugins for jQuery put their methods on the `$.fn` object, which extends the main jQuery object namespace, so that the method is callable from any jQuery object and applies to the current selection.

Comment: `$.fn` is a reference to the `jQuery.init` prototype. `jQuery.init` objects are returned by the jQuery factory function `jQuery` or `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector is `this` in the plugin.

For example:

```
$.fn.cycle = function() {
   console.log(this);
};

$('.headline').cycle(); //logs the `.headline` jQuery element
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eE6q2/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! This is a great example.

Comment: @JustinBoyd no problem ^_^ Happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

Your new function `$.fn.cycle` will be called in the context of the jQuery object:

```
var $foo;
$foo = $('.foo') //a jQuery object created by the factory function
$.fn.bar = function (a, b, c) {
  //within the function, `this` is the jQuery selection
  console.log(this, a, b, c);
};
$foo.bar(1, 2, 3); //will output $foo, 1, 2, 3
```

---

Typically jQuery plugins return `this` to maintain chainability. Additionally, they typically need to iterate over every element in the selection, so a common pattern to see is:

```
$.fn.foo = function () {
  //in foo, `this` is a jQuery.init object
  return this.each(function (index, element) {
    //in each, `this` is a DOM node
    var $this;
    $this = $(this);
    //do stuff
  });
};
```

Comment: This makes sense. I did a search for .fn on jquery.com and didn't come across anything. It makes sense now though. I guess I need to dev a plugin haha. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you run `$("selector")`, then jQuery already selects the appropriate elements. After that, the `.cycle` plugin function is called, in which `this` refers to the set of matched elements.

Selection is done by the jQuery core and not by plugins. Plugins "merely" do something with the elements that are passed to it. Even `$("selector");` will select elements although you don't do anything with them.